# How to add different font style in different store view Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have two store view in my magento2 store

1.English Language
2.Dutch Language

I want to add the different font in Dutch Store view. Could anybody please help me with that.

Comment: You can create multiple custom theme (one for English Store view and another for Dutch Store View ) and set   different Theme for Store views from Admin CONTENT->Configuration.

Comment: @PritamInfo24 Please put your comment as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: I have added my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple custom theme (one for English Store view and another for Dutch Store View ) and set separate Theme for each Store views from Admin CONTENT->Configuration.